# Getting SSLhandshake exception even after the security certificate is installed

Tags: jakarta-ee, jwebunit

" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
 sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
 find valid certification path to requested target"

I am getting the above excception when trying to connect to a website through jwebuint program. I have already imported the certificate keytool commmand.

I got strucked up here.
Please help me out.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all..

Solution: There will be two JRE's -one is under jdk1.2... and second one is directly under java folder.
**You need to install or import the website security certificates using keytool command under the jre which is in your ide's installed JRE's**

*For Eclipse IDE:
go to windows->preferences-> installed jre's*
Then it will show you the installed jre's path.

You need to import the certificate into that particular jre..

Using the keytool command is as follows:
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>keytool -import -alias aliasname -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts -file "D:\Softwares\certificates\mycert.cer"

Answer (score 0):

1. Run with the debug flags on (`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshhake`)
2. Do you instruct the JVM about the correct location of the keystore/truststore? (`javax.net.ssl.keyStore`, `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`, `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`)

Comment: @hanu: Just run your program with these options -Dparameter=value. Debugging options will turn on detailed info. Also run your program with: `java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshhake -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trustedcerts.jks com.example.MyClass`